# Is there a way to move rotativa completely outside of my mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

I installed Rotativa via nuget in order to render my mvc views as pdf documents. Works great :)

Here is what the project looks like.

```
-Core 
-Model
-WebMvc
--/Rotativa
--/various_dlls...
```

I want to break it out and move Rotativa to another project named Core. However when I do that there is an error since Rotativa folder must be inside my WebMvc project
Is there anything I can do to make the Rotativa work in the Core project like so?

```
-Core 
--/Rotativa
--/various_dlls...
-Model
-WebMvc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using Rotativa.1.6.1, I was able to move the 'Rotativa' folder completely outside of my project(s).  The same logic should apply for moving into your Core project.

In your MVC method, make sure to set the path, otherwise the library wouldn't find `wkhtmltopdf.exe`.

```
        ActionAsPdf result = new ActionAsPdf("Index");
        result.WkhtmltopdfPath = @"C:\path\Rotativa";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but here's a solution.

In your Web.config under appSettings

```
<add key="WkhtmltopdfPath" value="[path to wkhtmltopdf.exe]"/>
```

Then in WkhtmltopdfDriver.cs in Convert(string wkhtmltopdfPath, string switches, string html)

```
string s = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WkhtmltopdfPath"].ToString();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) {
    wkhtmltopdfPath = s;
}
```

This will override the default path.